Structural stability of Graphene
is it acceptable if I came up with around -8.5ev/atom for cohesive energy of graphene?, Literature is in the range 7.3-7.9 ev/atom
The formula used for cohesive energy calculation

Codes I have used
Total energy of single carbon atom
&CONTROL
    calculation = 'scf',
    prefix      = 'Isolated_C_atm',
    ! otudir      = '/tmp',
    pseudo_dir  = '/Users/thejanhasaranga/Downloads/CP/graphene2/Pseudo', 
    etot_conv_thr = 1.0d-6
           
 /

 &SYSTEM
    ibrav = 1,
    A = 15,
    nat  = 1,
    ntyp = 1,
    ecutwfc = 45.0,
    ecutrho = 360.0, 

    occupations = 'smearing',
    smearing = 'gaussian',
    degauss = 0.01,
 /
 
 &ELECTRONS
    conv_thr = 1.0d-8
 /
 
ATOMIC_SPECIES
   C  12.0107 C.pbe-rrkjus.UPF
   
ATOMIC_POSITIONS angstrom
   C            7.50       7.50       7.50
   
   
K_POINTS automatic
   3 3 3   0 0 0

`
Total energy of the system
&CONTROL
    calculation = 'scf',
    prefix      = 'Graphene3x3_PBE',
    ! otudir      = '/tmp',
    pseudo_dir  = '/Users/thejanhasaranga/Downloads/CP/graphene2/Pseudo',        
 /

 &SYSTEM
    ibrav     = 4,
    celldm(1) = 13.946177796,
    celldm(3) = 1.0,
    nat  = 18,
    ntyp = 1,
    ecutwfc = 40.0,
    ecutrho = 300.0, 

    occupations = 'smearing',
    smearing = 'gaussian',
    degauss = 0.01,
 /
 
 &ELECTRONS
    conv_thr = 1.0d-8
 /
 
ATOMIC_SPECIES
    C  12.0107 C.pbe-rrkjus.UPF
   
ATOMIC_POSITIONS angstrom
C            -0.0000000000        0.0000000000       14.9983095073
C             1.2351906153        0.7131376331       14.9983043713
C            -1.2351958125        2.1394194364       14.9982975844
C            -0.0000000000        2.8525614913       14.9982953470
C            -2.4704016687        4.2788587438       14.9982975844
C            -1.2352046254        4.9919986669       14.9982953470
C             2.4703894904        0.0000012324       14.9982975844
C             3.7055953465        0.7131400090       14.9982934038
C             1.2351958125        2.1394194364       14.9982975844
C             2.4703950384        2.8525696968       14.9982934038
C            -0.0000000000        4.2788529451       14.9982920850
C             1.2352046254        4.9919986669       14.9982953470
C             4.9408012027        0.0000012324       14.9982975844
C             6.1760000778        0.7131376331       14.9983043713
C             3.7055953465        2.1394264675       14.9982920652
C             4.9407956547        2.8525696968       14.9982934038
C             2.4704016687        4.2788587438       14.9982975844
C             3.7055953465        4.9920041463       14.9983043713



K_POINTS automatic
   3 3 1   0 0 0

`

It was the spin-polarized calculations that led to the issue. In both the isolated carbon atom and graphene calculations, I did not use spin-polarized DFT calculations. However, after reading this post [https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/12448/formation-energy-calculations/12451#12451], I decided to run spin-polarized DFT calculations with some identical parameters (such as k-points, ecutwfc, ecutrho, and starting magnetization) to match the previous calculations. This led me to obtain an energy value of -7.745 eV, which aligns with the literature.
Thank you to everyone who contributed to the post I mentioned in the answer.
